# Why can't the length of a first order statement be a nonstandard number?

Tags: first-order-logic

If a first order statement could have a nonstandard length, and proofs could have nonstandard lengths, then you could prove that PA must have nonstandard numbers by proving there exists a number x=S(S(...0...)) for a nonstandard amount of S's. As PA has the natural numbers as a model this is a contradiction.
So when describing the rules of first order logic, how are nonstandard length statements and proofs forbidden?

Comment: They are not forbidden. There can be formulas of non standard length.

Comment: What does it mean to have nonstandard length? The length of a formula is a natural number (of whatever appropriate ambient universe this discussion takes places on), by definition. Nonstandard numbers are not natural numbers, by definition. If your ambient universe is a nonstandard model with nonstandard integers, then formulas, in the sense of your ambient universe, may well have nonstandard length. Of course, from the viewpoint of the ambient universe, their length is just an ordinary number.

Comment: " PA must have nonstandard numbers ". I am not sure what this means. Theories do not have objects. Do you mean a model of PA must have ...? Well, we already know that. Do you mean PA must prove the existence of ...?

Comment: I mean if you could have nonstandard length proofs, you could prove a nonstandard length statement $\exists x, x=S(S(...(0)...))$, and that x must be a nonstandard number in any model. I am confused how first order statements can only have a natural number as their length when you need first order logic to attempt to define natural numbers in the first place. Or am I wrong with saying there is a proof for that statement, because first order PA has no axiom saying $\forall x \exists y, y=S(x)$,instead induction must be used to show that the successor of a number is still a number?